# jQuery trigger delegation as soon as created

Tags: jquery, ajax, delegates

I'm trying to make an automatically disappearing notification box, the notification box is loaded trough ajax so I cannot use the `$(document).ready();`.

I found the nifty `.delegate()` function which I'm using extensively, so basically now ajax creates a new `<div class="fade">Stupid monkey!</div>` and I'd like it to disappear after 2 seconds based on the class definition, this is what I've got so far:

```
// ajax request handler
jQuery('#message').append('<div class="fade">Stupid monkey!</div>');

jQuery('body').delegate('.fade', eventType, function()
{
    jQuery(this).delay(2000).slideUp(500, function()
    {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Whatever I replace `eventType` with I can't trigger my handler right after I create the element. I've tried `ready`, `load` and all sorts of alternatives... `click` works but isn't what I need and I can't trigger a `click` on the anonymous `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('body').delegate('.fade', eventType, function()
{
    jQuery(this).delay(2000).slideUp(500, function()
    {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
});

jQuery('<div class="fade">Stupid monkey!</div>').appendTo("#message").trigger(eventType);
```

You can take advantage of chaining.  Create the element, append it to your element and then call trigger on the newly added div.