# JQuery cant find dynamicly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to insert html into dynamicly created table (Im using datatables). In document.ready() function, after initialising datatable i put

```
$("div.menuContainer").html('<select id="dropdownMenu1"> </select>');
```

and it doesnt work. But if i enter this line in browser console after loading page it works. What to do folks?

Comment: try using live().. https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Try executing on $(window).load()

Comment: But what event should I bind to it? I just want to load html into when is created.

Comment: It means that your table is not yet rendered. You need to invoke this code once rendering is complete. Use corresponding events and callbacks DataTables provides.

Comment: You can put your code within timeout function. This may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rendering of the DataTable is asynchronous operation (assuming that it also needs to fetch some server-side data), you can't just execute your code *after* table initialization: it's still not rendered and the HTML structure is not ready.

Instead, use DataTables API events. In your case [`init`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/init) event should do the trick:

```
$('.table').on('init.dt', function() {
    $("div.menuContainer").html('<select id="dropdownMenu1"> </select>');
});
```

Or you can use [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) callback in table configuration.

Comment: You are genious! it worked! Thanks you very much, 
Ive spent hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Accessing static parent and use find

```
$(use_parent_static_div_id).find(dynamic_element_id);
```

here parent means parent div of  **dynamicly created table**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure div.menuContainer exists?

Try this after dynamic insert:

```
$("body").find("div.menuContainer").html('<select id="dropdownMenu1"></select>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use ['delegate' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121716/jquery-trigger-delegation-as-soon-as-created) on the parent class.

> Delegate attaches a handler to one or more events for all elements
>   that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set
>   of root elements.

You may find this answer useful:
[jQuery trigger delegation as soon as created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121716/jquery-trigger-delegation-as-soon-as-created)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `datatable` `fnInitComplete` function.

```
"fnInitComplete": function () {
$("div.menuContainer").html('<select id="dropdownMenu1"> </select>');
}
```